# is it possible to use adb on an unauthorized device?

Tags: android, adb

Is it possible to use ADB on an unauthorized device?

I need to use it to remotely control my phone from my laptop, since my screen is broken and I need to backup some data from my phone

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**No, it isn't.** Unless you happen to have access to the device vendor keys, which are probably kept locked in a basement of a safehouse, you cannot access it without proper interactive authentication. If you do somehow have these keys (i.e. you are an OEM or you rooted the phone (in which case you don't need to do any of this)), you can just `export ADB_VENDOR_KEYS=...` and it should authorise automatically.

Comment: i rooted my phone, but i'm not sure that i have the vendor keys. and where should i use `export ADB_VENDOR_KEYS=...` when i have the vendor keys, i tried `adb export` and it give me unknown command error. sorry if my question seems stupid, i'm not really familiar with adb

Comment: Well presumably you rooted it using TWRP? So just enter TWRP and use that.